# How to check syslog.d is running

Tags: debian, logging, daemon, debian-wheezy, syslogd

My syslog is running correctly but out of curiosity how to check that syslog daemon is running. Is there anyway I could check the status like apache

```
root@server1:/etc# /etc/init.d/apache2 status
Apache2 is running (pid 12894).
```

I'm running Debian wheezy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pidof` utility to check whether pretty much any program is running (if it gives out at least one pid, the program is running).  If you are using syslog-ng, this would be `pidof syslog-ng`; if you are using syslogd, it would be `pidof syslogd`.

Comment: @sg552 : `pgrep` is another possibility.

Answer (score 13):

Debian uses rsyslog and you can check it is running pretty much exactly like checking apache is running

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog status
[ ok ] rsyslogd is running.
```

Or you could use the service command (which does pretty much the same thing)

```
service rsyslog status
[ ok ] rsyslogd is running.
```

Comment: I'm using `syslogd`. I install `rsyslogd` just now because I think the service command is much simple. Thanks again.